# Matching multiple in Regex vs Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have a very complex set of variances that I need to account for.  Is it better to write a regular expression that matches all of them or to write individual ones in Java and test each with-in an if-then block?

I can't even come up with the regular express that would match every case so it maybe a moot point:

Here is the input:

- **CN666SEEEI**
- **FOC000007HW** (2190000002)
- **FHK10AAAAAA** (2850000004)
- **JAB031444BA** (3108888022)
- S/N **JAE14445WW7**
- Serial :**FOC0818S08R** Model : Cisc
- Serial_Number: **FHK10HHHQ4**
- Model:CISCO7200VXR, SN:**36555555**
- Cisco CISCO3845 SN: **FGL15555532**
- CISCO2831 **FHK13XXXX1E**
- CISCO1851 SN: **FHK1XXXX55M**
- CISCO2821   SN: **FHK1333F11J**
- CISCO2921/K9, SN: **FHK1444FF7F**
- Cisco 1941/k9 Sn: **FHK13HHHTQ**
- CISCO2121 SN: **FHKFFFFFFEY**
- WS-C2970-24TC-L, SN: **FOCXXXXZ34K**
- WS-C3760-24TS-S, SN: **FDOXXXXX0F6**
- 38 42 42 42 42 42 42 44 42 42

Now I need to extract out the serial number -- really the first line is the simplest form, the rest are **hidden** within the string.  The last one is completely invalid and should match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for the examples given.

Though, the "very complex set of variances" may need to be outlined in detail for a watertight solution.

```
String str = "CN666SEEEI\n" +
    "FOC000007HW (2190000002)\n" +
    "FHK10AAAAAA (2850000004)\n" +
    "JAB031444BA (3108888022)\n" +
    "S/N JAE14445WW7\n" +
    "Serial :FOC0818S08R Model : Cisc\n" +
    "Serial_Number: FHK10HHHQ4\n" +
    "Model:CISCO7200VXR, SN:36555555\n" +
    "Cisco CISCO3845 SN: FGL15555532\n" +
    "CISCO2831 FHK13XXXX1E\n" +
    "CISCO1851 SN: FHK1XXXX55M\n" +
    "CISCO2821 SN: FHK1333F11J\n" +
    "CISCO2921/K9, SN: FHK1444FF7F\n" +
    "Cisco 1941/k9 Sn: FHK13HHHTQ\n" +
    "CISCO2121 SN: FHKFFFFFFEY\n" +
    "WS-C2970-24TC-L, SN: FOCXXXXZ34K\n" +
    "WS-C3760-24TS-S, SN: FDOXXXXX0F6\n" +
    "38 42 42 42 42 42 42 44 42 42";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile( "\\b(?!CISCO)[A-Z\\d]{8,}(?=\\s|$)" ).matcher( str ); 

while ( m.find() ) {
    System.out.println( m.group() );
}
```

I assumed you meant that the last one should *not* match.

Comment: holy #*$# I didn't think there was a way to write a single regex to cover them all.

Answer (score 1):

I would split the strings into different groups and apply different patterns to them based on that initial grouping.

The first group could be something simple like `str.contains(":")` i.e. that the string contains a semicolon. Then break this down further, does this next group contain the word 'Cisco'. After you have broken that list down into some easier to handle sublists like below it will be much easier to write Regexs for each.

Doesn't have 'SN' or ':' or 'Cisco'

```
CN666SEEEI
FOC000007HW (2190000002)
FHK10AAAAAA (2850000004)
JAB031444BA (3108888022)
```

Then break this down further -

Contains ' ' (space):

```
FOC000007HW (2190000002)
FHK10AAAAAA (2850000004)
JAB031444BA (3108888022)
```

Does not -

```
CN666SEEEI
```

These two groups don't even need a regex, you just extract the right bit after splitting.

Use the examples provided to break down your list and apply simple regexs to each!